# Is there an R library for plotting a linear regression across a gradient colored scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

[image]

Hello, I would like to plot a similar figure, is there a way to do it with ggplot or other similar R library? I Can provide dummy data if eventually needed for proper further explanations.
Thanks for your help!

edit:Ok, so here is the code for plotting a scatter plot with values gradient as well as the code for plotting a linear regression

How do I combine both in a single plot? thanks for your help!

```
library(ggplot2)
data("mtcars")

#code for plotting a gradient colored scatter plot
p1<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=qsec)) + geom_point()
p1

#code for a quick linear regression
fit1 <- lm(wt~ mpg, data = mtcars)

p2<-ggplot(fit1$model, aes_string(x = names(fit1$model)[2], y = names(fit1$model)[1]),) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") +
  labs(title="Linear regression between wt and mpg")
p2
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Yes, if you could post some dummy data and some example code of what you've tried so far that would be helpful.

Comment: `p1 + geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "#000000")` . There is no need to calculate the model separately for the plot. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Thank for your kind welcome teunbrand! (problem solved, thank you Markus!)

Comment: If your problem is solved you can write up your own answer to it ...